# Combine 2 separate results mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on an eCommerce based website using `MongoDb`.

In my db collection I have 2 type of documents

1. Company details Item

   `{ doc_type : 'company',
     name : 'Acer',
     type : 'Laptops',
     helpline : '1800-200-000'
   }`
2. Item Details

   `{doc_type : "item",
     item_id : 1001,
     price : 2000,
     discount : 20}`

Now in product page i need to get data from both document.

so, first i run

```
db.collection.find({doc_type:'item', item_id : 1001 });
```

to show product data and then

```
 db.collection.find({doc_type:'company', name: "Acer"});
```

to get company data.

Is their any way to reduce these 2 calls to one and get data in single result set.

like

```
{
 company : { //company data},
 item : { //item details }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the sample output that you have shared, along with the `$match` and `$group` stages, I have added a `$project` stage.

```
db.col.aggregate([
 {
  $match: 
  {
   $or: [
    {doc_type:'item', item_id : 1001 },
    {doc_type:'company', name: 'Acer'}
   ]
  }
 },
 {
  $group: 
  {
   _id: null,
   "company_name": {$max: "$name"},
   "company_type": {$max: "$type"},
   "company_helpline": {$max: "$helpline"},
   "item_price": {$max: "$price"},
   "item_discount": {$max: "$discount"}
  }
 },
 {
  $project: 
  {
   _id: 0,
   'company' : {
    'name': '$company_name',
    'type': '$company_type',
    'helpline': '$company_helpline',
   },
   'item' : {
    'price': '$item_price',
    'discount': '$item_discount'
   }
  }
 }
]).pretty()
```

Output :

```
{
        "company" : {
                "name" : "Acer",
                "type" : "Laptops",
                "helpline" : "1800-200-000"
        },
        "item" : {
                "price" : 2000,
                "discount" : 20
        }
}
```

Comment: does that effect performance as items table contain 3-4 lakh records... and sometimes company data needed to be merged with 50-60k item records ?

Comment: No, this won't affect the performance. Since we are using `$match` stage of pipeline, very few documents are going to be carried forward to the next levels. In case you face a memory issue, try using `$allowDiskUse` with value true.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using aggregation using a `$match` and a `$group` stage. 
The query would be :

```
db.it.aggregate([
{$match: 
    {$or: [
        {doc_type:'item', item_id : 1001 },
        {doc_type:'company', name: "Acer"}
        ]
    }
},
 {$group: 
    {_id: null,
     "compagny_name": {$max: "$name"},
     "compagny_type": {$max: "$type"},
     "compagny_helpline": {$max: "$helpline"},
     "item_price": {$max: "$price"},
     "item_discount": {$max: "$discount"}
    }
}] )
```

this output :

```
{
   "_id":null,
   "compagny_name":"Acer",
   "compagny_type":"Laptops",
   "compagny_helpline":"1800-200-000",
   "item_price":2000,
   "item_discount":20
}
```

Comment: is aggregating a permanent change in data or generated every-time the user requests ?

Comment: @atulquest93 No, this won't change the data in your collection. It's generated every time you run the quey

Comment: thanks ! one more little doubt does that effect performance ? Like every-time we  are merging one collection with other ..  or when collection contains more than 3-4 lac rows ? Like in my case their can be 1 lac items from a particular company.

Comment: @atulquest93 actually your not merging collections, but document. This is not a join (we would use $lookup then) but only a grouping. As there is a $match at the beginning of the pipeline, the $group stage applies only on few documents, so it should be very fast. You should try it and look at the explain to have a better idea od it's performance

Comment: ohh .. means `$lookup` will make a permanent change in document structure ? So, if data is supposed to be updated regularly in documents then grouping is best option or otherwise `$lookup`. right  ?

Comment: @atulquest93 Aggregation pipeline does not change document structure in database, it only change the output structure. Here your documents 'items' and 'compagny' are in the same collections, so you can't perform a $lookup. And for performance concern, just make sure that the fields you're filtering on are properly indexed (ie 'doc_type', 'item_id' and 'name')